# Reading in a text file in iOS

Tags: ios, textview, uitextview

How do I read in a text file into a textView? I have many different text files and the user selects which one is displayed, so that is why I don't just have a file name in there. I'm really confused about why this doesn't work. I found it right on the Apple Developer site in the section about reading from files to strings.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"%@" ofType:@"txt"];
textFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsofFile:path];
textView.text = textFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

`-pathForResource:ofType:` doesn't accept a format string; replace the `@"%@"` with a string containing the base name of the file (i.e. the filename minus the .txt extention).

You've also got a mismatch on the second and third lines: you probably meant:

```
textView.text = textFile;
```

Comment: ok, that makes sense. What if I don't know what base name to use because that depends on what the user selects?
thanks for catching that. That is indeed what I meant.

Comment: then use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",USER_SELECTION]` for the pathForResource string

Comment: @ebeth: The name has to come from somewhere, right? What were you planning to substitute for the `%@` in the format string you were trying to use? Just use that *instead of* the format string.