# txt file to string

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading in a text file in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932162/reading-in-a-text-file-in-ios)

This is a really dumb question but once I have a txt file at a path in my iOS app. How do I convert the txt file into a string that I can put in a UITextView. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:yourFilePath encoding:error:]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```